# What is the dash equivalent for .bashrc?

Tags: unity-dash

Where should I put personal shell configurations when using dash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no default file, you should set its name in the `ENV` environment variable. So add to your `.profile` the line

```
ENV=$HOME/.shinit; export ENV
```

so that `.shinit` becomes the equivalent of `.bashrc`.

But take into account that `dash` is not suitable for interactive use, given that do not provide any line editing capabilities (this can be solved: see [How to have editing capabilities in command line apps that do not provide them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86905/how-to-have-editing-capabilities-in-command-line-apps-that-do-not-provide-them)).

Comment: you can `set -o vi` or `set -o emacs` for "interactive" usage.