# trying to delete a tab character in terminal only deletes one space

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using the Windows Subsystem for Linux; I don't know if this is relevant.  Anyway, suppose I'm running cat at a terminal, and I enter `2.718\te` where `\t` is an actual tab character.  The screen now looks like this: `2.718   e`.  Now I realize I made a mistake, and I should give a few more digits of precision.  (Whatever, this example is made up.  The point is that I make mistakes when typing.)  This should be easy: my keyboard has a backspace key :)  I hit it once, and the `e` disappears.  So far so good.  I hit it again and ... one space disappears.  I hit it one more time, and one more space disappears, even though by now I should have erased the 8.  I now press enter, and cat echoes back at me... `2.71`.  So, apparently, I did erase the 8, but the contents of my screen got de-synched from the ground truth in the terminal driver.

So, my question is why.  More importantly, what to do about it?

Comment: found workaround rlwrap seems to fix the problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/86905/how-to-have-editing-capabilities-in-command-line-apps-that-do-not-provide-them/86908

Comment: Apparently, your tab is expanded to 8 spaces instead of a `\t` character. You can check this by saving the output to a file and running `od -c file`. You should see that there are spaces there and not a `\t`.

Comment: I thought of that.  I tried `cat > t.txt`, followed by `wc`.  It is NOT being expanded to spaces.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the `readline` implementation on Windows does so then. Could you confirm with `cat file | od - c`, just in case though?

Comment: od says it's \t

Comment: canonical mode terminal input doesn't involve `readline`, and this should probably be filed as a bug on the GitHub bug tracker for WSL.

Comment: JdeBP: thank you, I should have thought of that!