# Is there a startup file for dash not bash?

Tags: dash-shell

I put alises to .bashrc file however it doesnt sourced when it comes to /bin/sh which is linked to dash shell. Is there a compatiable version of sh terminal startup file for **dash**.
I have tried .profile, .bash_profile etc.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I don't know the answer, but someone else might. One thing to know: `.bsah_profile` are both `.bashrc` for the `bash` shell. I don't know about `.profile`, but at least for the first two, they are not for `/bin/sh`.

Comment: There is no *default* initialization file for non-login dash shells, however you can define one of your choosing as described here [What is the dash equivalent for .bashrc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86139/what-is-the-dash-equivalent-for-bashrc)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the dash equivalent for .bashrc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86139/what-is-the-dash-equivalent-for-bashrc)